# Definition of step function

Tags: real-analysis

If I havequestion regrading the definition of step function

Definition: A step function is a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ for some intervals $[a,b]$ that takes finitely many values $a_1,a_2,.......,a_n$ and for each $ i=1,2,......,n$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(a_i)$ is an interval . Is it correct? Without adding the inverse is Finit Union of intervals .

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allow $f^{-1}(a_i)$ to be a finite union of
intervals rather than requiring it to be a single interval.
The [boxcar function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoxcarFunction.html),
$$
\Pi_{p,q}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \qquad\text{if $p\leq x\leq q$}\\
0 \qquad\text{otherwise},
\end{cases} 
$$
would be considered a step function by most writers, but if 
$\Pi_{p,q}$ is defined on $[a,b]$ and $a < p < q < b$ then
$\Pi_{p,q}^{-1}(0) = [a,p) \cup (q,b]$, which is not an interval.